# Hyperlink in SQL

Tags: sql

If you save a text in SQL, is is possible to include a hyperlink in that same text?

When I save `<a href='http://duckduckgo.com'>duck</a>` in my SQL database, it gets displayed as plain text and not as a hyperlink when selected and displayed on my website.

Is it even possible to include hyperlinks like this and if not, what is a better solution?

edit; im using node.js and react

Comment: Most likely text from your database is rendered in such a way that tags and special characters are encoded, so that they display on your website. This is typically a good thing, to avoid someone adding HTML in their username or whatnot and you just blindly rendering it as HTML causing HTML injection. What is the source of that text?

Comment: In MySQL workbench, the specific string is saved like this: 

'<a href=\'http://duckduckgo.com\'>duck</a>'

I tried to remove some charachters to make it fit but I got an SQL error.

The whole query in MySQL looks like this: UPDATE `schema_1`.`post_data` SET `post_text` = '<a href=\'http://duckduckgo.com\'>duck</a>' WHERE (`post_id` = '4');

The text is suppose to be on a website I am creating

Comment: How are you outputting it to the page?  Include the relevant data in your question

Comment: Via node.js and react

Comment: SQL is agnostic to whatever text you store in a *varchar* column, if you insert a html link you'll get back the same html link; it sounds like your question should be about the JS framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever DBMS you are using most likely does not implement a "Hyperlink" data type. You will need to save the hyperlink as text and then get your application to display the hyperlink.

It sounds like you are storing HTML, so you could simply open that HTML in a web browser to see the link. You will need to have an application to pull the HTML from your database and display it to the user.

Depending on your DBMS, there are multiple libraries available to connect to a database. Try googling your DBMS and a programming language to find a library that suits your needs.

For example, [npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/) is a library to connect to postgres using .NET.